# authorization to select datetime in windows form

Tags: c#

i have datetimepicker on form , and 1 txtbox where we have name of users.

now i want allow superuser "sa" to access full calander, but i want normal user make entry with current date in system.
i have use following code but not working for me.
how to resloved this??
thanks in advace please help

```
enter code here

        if (txtSupervisor.Text != "sa")
            {

                dateTimePicker1.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now; 

            }
enter code here
```

Comment: It is not exactly a silver bullet security

Comment: ya i knoe sir but pls help to resolved

Comment: now i want allow superuser "sa" to access full calander, but i want normal user make entry with current date in system.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the datetime picker control when the user is not **'sa'** and set the current date to text box and make that text box readonly. And if the user is SA then make the datetime picketr control visible.

Comment: but i want to save date in one column in database , so in that case what i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are not giving any security here by just checking the username in the textbox. But you can do your requirement by the following code

```
            if (txtSupervisor.Text == "sa")
            {
                SettingManger.Instance.IsAdmin = Enumerator.AdminType.SUPERADMIN;    
            }
            else // no need for else if statement
            {
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
            }
```

Comment: now i want allow superuser "sa" to access full calander, but i want normal user make entry with current date in system.

Comment: if (SettingManger.Instance.User != "sa")
                {

                    dateTimePicker1.MinDate = dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now; 
                   
                }

Comment: resloved chk above comment